# Unique Game Players Count by Pandas

Tags: pandas, count

I have dataframe of customer id's and Game names. I want to calculate the count of those customer id's who have just played only 1 particular game

My Dataframe is like

```
id     game
1      Rummy
2      Ludo
3      Panda
4      8 Ball Pool
5      Rummy
2      Rummy
4      Ludo
```

My desired output should be

```
Game    Count
Rummy   2
Panda   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df.drop_duplicates('id', keep=False)['game'].value_counts()
print (s)
Rummy    2
Panda    1
Name: game, dtype: int64
```

If want 2 column DataFrame:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates('id', keep=False)['game']
         .value_counts()
         .rename_axis('game')
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
    game  count
0  Rummy      2
1  Panda      1
```